# Fixed points of elements of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, symmetric-groups

Given an element $\sigma \in S_n$ , I wish to calculate number of elements $\gamma \in S_n$ such that $\sigma \circ \gamma \circ \sigma^{-1} = \gamma $.
I suspect the number to be $$\frac{n!}{1^{n_1}n_1!2^{n_2}n_2!3^{n_3}n_3!\ldots n^{n_n}n_n!}$$
where $(n_1,n_2,n_3,\ldots,n_n)$ is the cycle type of $\sigma$. However I am not able to prove this.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Edit: As suggested in the comment orbit-stabiliser theorem is useful. Also I notice that conjugating does not change cycle type. Thus size of orbit is $$\frac{n!}{1^{n_1}n_1!2^{n_2}n_2!3^{n_3}n_3!\ldots n^{n_n}n_n!}$$
so by orbit stabiliser theorem the cardinality of set of fixed points is $${1^{n_1}n_1!2^{n_2}n_2!3^{n_3}n_3!\ldots n^{n_n}n_n!}$$

Comment: You can compute the size of the conjugacy class (orbit) of $\gamma$ using that number. Then use the orbit-stabilizer theorem to count fixed points (stabilizer): you will get the result is the denominator.

Comment: It will be helpful to state your source (where you are reading from) and why you expect this number to be the case. Is it because it works out for certain easy-to-check cycle types? Also, you must be aware of the fact that conjugacy is a group action and therefore the orbit-stabilizer theorem is available to you. Stating these pieces of information will be very helpful for others who are trying to solve your question.

Comment: The centralizer of a permutation in the symmetric group is a direct product of wreath products. From this you find your formula is correct. You can search for "centralizer of permutation" to find many duplicate questions on this site and around the web.